# how variables stored in data segment while compiling are mapped to virtual memory while executing the c program

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how a executable file (of a C Program) is mapped to virtual memory while executing it. I read on the internet that during the compilation stage, different segments (like data segment, code segment, bss) will be created and the variables will be placed in the segments. How these are going to present in the executable file. Do these segments only have offset addresses?

Do these segments will still exist at the time of execution? If they exist, how these segments will be mapped to virtual memory while execution? Can any one please explain me the complete process of these segments mapping?

Comment: The specifics will vary from platform to platform.  Here is a good, straightforward discussion for Linux: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/